# Spiritual chemistry spell

Tags: knowledge, wordplay, lateral-thinking

What three abbreviations can be used to spell Ghost and God?

This is meant to be elementary but there is a twist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

> Ho (Holmium)
>  Gd (Gadolinium)
>  Ts (Tennessine)
>
>  Which are all elements of the periodic table

Comment: That’s a good answer and one I didn’t spot. Can you find a second which includes a twist?

Comment: I’m going to accept the answer and ask again with a rephrasing.