# Spiritual chemistry take two

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

When the three meet there’s a Ghost.

When one departs and another gains weight God remains.

What elementary abbreviations do I speak of?

I am looking for an exact answer - no spare letters.

A hint which is not necessary to solve (the solution has been found):

> I am Alpha and Omega, the beginning and the end, the first and the last. *Revelation 22:13*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The original three are

> Oganesson (Og), Hydrogen (H), and Tennessine (Ts) to spell gHOsT.

When

> Tennessine departs, and Hydrogen gains weight — adding a neutron to Hydrogen forms Deuterium (commonly abbreviated as D), then gOD remains.

Comment: @El-Guest God guessed!

Comment: Love your hint! I had noticed that, actually — a very nice clue.

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I have an answer that may work:

> The elements are
>  1. `Ca` (Calcium) or `Ac` (Actinium)
>  2. `Se` (Selenium) or `Es` (Einsteinium)
>  3. `Pr` (Praseodymium)
>  They spell 'CASPER', who is a **ghost** from pop culture ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Casper_the_Friendly_Ghost)).
>
>  `Ca`/`Ac` departs, and the second element from above which you *didn't* use in the initial three (`Se` or `Es`) enters.
>  So now you have `Se`, `Es`, and `Pr`, which may be used to spell 'PERSES', the Titan **god** of destruction from Greek mythology ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perses_(Titan))).

Comment: It wasn't what i was looking for but that is very clever and creative. My solution is a lot more direct than that and I think it will be obvious that it is correct when it is found. But there is a twist that needs to be seen hence lateral-thinking tag.

Comment: I've adjusted the clue again which doesn't rule out this answer entirely, but hopefully hints more strongly at what I am looking for.

Comment: @David Is the essential idea of using chemical symbols correct?

Answer (score 1):

The answer from [Spiritual chemistry spell](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/101469/spiritual-chemistry-spell) still applies here:

> 1. Ho (Holmium)
>  2. Gd (Gadolinium)
>  3. Ts (Tennessine)
>  One departs (`Ts`), but 'God' is still there because of `Ho` and `Gd`.

Comment: What you have there is Ghostd and Ghod. The answer I am looking for is more exact than that.

Comment: that sounds impossible, because if the starting three just spell 'ghost' without any extra alphabets, there's no 'D' to spell 'God' for the remaining two when one leaves .. ?

Comment: Knowledge and lateral thinking are required.

Comment: But good try. I have had to update the question to make my wording more precise.